# Jquery: How to read array object based on input

Tags: jquery, arrays, forms, variables, object

I'm designing an application that collects input from the users via a form. Based on the input, the application will search the array objects for corresponding value and display the value to the users.

I'm stuck at the process of selecting a particular value in the array objects. Below is a simplified version of my application. The array objects have 2 attributes: gender (male/female) and work status (full-time/part-time).

I named a variable called "gender" to convert the user's input into index (0 or 1), and use that index in the .val() to identify the object (male/female).

```
if($('#inputgender').val()=="Male"){var gender=0;}
if($('#inputgender').val()=="Female"){var gender=1;}
```

Using the same approach, I named another variable called "workstatus" to convert the user's input into the name of the array (fulltime or parttime), but .val() could not read that variable. It read data[gender].workstatus as undefined.

```
if($('#inputworkstatus').val()=="Full-time"){var workstatus="fulltime";}
if($('#inputworkstatus').val()=="Part-time"){var workstatus="parttime";}
console.log(data[gender].workstatus);
$("#outputbox").text("Your number is " + data[gender].workstatus);
```

Any better way to build this application assuming my dataset is slightly bigger than the example used here, with maybe 4 or 5 attributes (age, country, marriage status)?

Thanks.

Below is the full code.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<form name="myForm" id="workForm" method="get" action="#">
Your gender:<br>
<SELECT NAME="gender" SIZE="1" id="inputgender">
<OPTION>Male
<OPTION>Female
</SELECT>
<br><br>

Your work status:<br>
<SELECT NAME="workstatus" SIZE="1" id="inputworkstatus">
<OPTION>Full-time
<OPTION>Part-time
</SELECT>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
<INPUT TYPE="reset">
</form>

<span id="outputbox"></span>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

var data = [{"gender":"male","fulltime":10,"parttime":20},
{"gender":"female","fulltime":30,"parttime":40}];

$(document).ready(function(){

$("form").submit(function( event ) {
    if($('#inputgender').val()=="Male"){var gender=0;}
    if($('#inputgender').val()=="Female"){var gender=1;}
    if($('#inputworkstatus').val()=="Full-time"){var workstatus="fulltime";}
    if($('#inputworkstatus').val()=="Part-time"){var workstatus="parttime";}
    console.log(data[gender].workstatus);
    $("#outputbox").text("Your number is " + data[gender].workstatus);

event.preventDefault(); 
    });

});

</script>
```

Comment: jQuery 1.4.2? Isn't that a bit old?

Comment: you're missing the closing `</option>` tags

Comment: @JaredFarrish right, forgot to update the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access an object property with a variable you need to use bracket notation so it should be:

```
console.log(data[gender][workstatus]);
```